# multiple providers linux nat configuration

Tags: linux-networking

I have linux box that serves as a router/firewall and has 2 internet providers connected to. I'd like to make load-sharing with failover using it.
I did such thing many years ago and it was pretty simple - just add 2 routing tables for 2 connections and then use 2 default routings with the weight required:

```
 ip route add default scope global nexthop via 1.2.3.4 dev dev100 weight 10
```

And then linux will randomly add routes to the cache, dividing connections between links.

But now I found that it does not work anymore with linux 3.16, and there's no route cache anymore and all my old scripts are not working and I cannot setup the connection.

My configuration is:

```
-------------
- ip route list table prov1
default via 217.147.175.129 dev eth1
46.164.150.48/29 dev eth2  scope link  src 46.164.150.51
127.0.0.0/8 dev lo  scope link
172.16.0.0/16 dev br0  scope link  src 172.16.1.1
217.147.175.128/25 dev eth1  scope link  src 217.147.175.165
-------------
- ip route list table prov2
default via 46.164.150.49 dev eth2
46.164.150.48/29 dev eth2  scope link  src 46.164.150.51
127.0.0.0/8 dev lo  scope link
172.16.0.0/16 dev br0  scope link  src 172.16.1.1
217.147.175.128/25 dev eth1  scope link  src 217.147.175.165
-------------
- ip route list table main
default
        nexthop via 217.147.175.129  dev eth1 weight 10
        nexthop via 46.164.150.49  dev eth2 weight 10
46.164.150.48/29 dev eth2  proto kernel  scope link  src 46.164.150.51
172.16.0.0/16 dev br0  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.16.1.1
176.37.229.77 via 217.147.175.129 dev eth1
195.12.244.0/22 via 217.147.175.129 dev eth1
213.248.127.0/24 via 217.147.175.129 dev eth1
217.147.175.128/25 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 217.147.175.165
239.0.0.0/8 dev br0  scope link
--------------
- ip route list table default
--------------------
- ip rule list
0:      from all lookup local
32756:  from all fwmark 0xb iif br0 lookup prov2
32757:  from all fwmark 0xa iif br0 lookup prov1
32758:  from 46.164.150.51 lookup prov2
32760:  from 217.147.175.165 lookup prov1
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default

 cat /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
#
# reserved values
#
255     local
254     main
253     default
0       unspec
#
# local
#
#1      inr.ruhep
10       prov1
11       prov2
```

But with this configuration everything is working fine from the host itself, but does not work for NATed IPs behind this host. To be more specific - that what I see from NATed host:

```
vik@Pro:~ $ ping 193.193.193.100
PING 193.193.193.100 (193.193.193.100): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 193.193.193.100: icmp_seq=0 ttl=59 time=3.737 ms
64 bytes from 193.193.193.100: icmp_seq=1 ttl=59 time=4.198 ms
64 bytes from 193.193.193.100: icmp_seq=2 ttl=59 time=3.934 ms
Request timeout for icmp_seq 3
64 bytes from 193.193.193.100: icmp_seq=4 ttl=60 time=3.650 ms
64 bytes from 193.193.193.100: icmp_seq=5 ttl=60 time=3.616 ms
Request timeout for icmp_seq 6
64 bytes from 193.193.193.100: icmp_seq=7 ttl=60 time=3.509 ms
64 bytes from 193.193.193.100: icmp_seq=8 ttl=60 time=3.417 ms
64 bytes from 193.193.193.100: icmp_seq=9 ttl=60 time=3.635 ms
Request timeout for icmp_seq 10
```

As you can notice, a lot of packets were just lost. And hosts behind this linux router cannot open webpages etc - connection is just dropped:

```
$ telnet google.com 80
Trying 173.194.113.201...
Connected to google.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
get / http/1.0

Connection closed by foreign host.
```

I tried to find some manuals and found an advice to CONNMARK packets like that:

```
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -i eth1 --dst 217.147.175.165 -m state --state NEW,RELATED -j CONNMARK --set-mark 10
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -i eth2 --dst 46.164.150.51   -m state --state NEW,RELATED -j CONNMARK --set-mark 11

iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -i br0 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j CONNMARK --restore-mark
```

But it didn't help at all.
Please help )

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the packet loss occurs as the packets returns different from the source route. IP routing is stateless. I think you could follow the this [link](http://linux-ip.net/html/adv-multi-internet.html) to archive the dual-wan.

Comment: Water is wet, routing is stateless, packets are lost ;)
Could you be more specific please?
I read this link and found nothing useful there. It's the same what I've done, isn't it?
I did some traces and I see that packets are lost somewhere in the NAT - I mean, that I see, for example, 3 incoming packets from the NAted host and just 2 NATed packets sent to the wan host then.